# I always get this error "unknow param 0x00008824 glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x0000882"

Tags: java, android, firebase

when i am trying to create a new email and password account with the app on firebase. it does not work.

Logcat shows this error

2019-04-01 16:24:35.375 5841-5867/com.example.login E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
2019-04-01 16:24:35.375 5841-5867/com.example.login E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da

Run shows this error

E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
    glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824

I have searched everything, but no solution worked. e.g. upgrading android from 6.0.0 to 6.01 or higher.

```
package com.example.login;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

    public class LoginEmailSignupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        TextView tvText;
        EditText etEmail, etPasswort, etDeinName;
        Button btRegistriert;

        private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
        private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_email_signup);

            tvText = findViewById(R.id.tvText);
            etEmail = findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
            etPasswort = findViewById(R.id.etPasswort);
            etDeinName = findViewById(R.id.etDeinName);
            btRegistriert = findViewById(R.id.btRegistriert);

            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

            mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth)
                {

                    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AppStartActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                }
            }
            };
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStart()
        {
            super.onStart();
            mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }

        public void register(View view)
        {
            String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
            String name = etDeinName.getText().toString();
            String pass = etPasswort.getText().toString();

            if (!email.isEmpty() && !name.isEmpty() && !pass.isEmpty())
            {
                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult>task) {
                        Log.d("Reg", "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fehler bei der Registrierung", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Du bist registriert", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Bitte befülle die Felder", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

I would like to create a new user with an email address and password on firebase.

Answer (score 0):

i have found the solution.

You have to enter a valid Email Adress and a Password with the necessary safety requirements.